# How to create this `through`` association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

`Organization` and `Link` are associated through `Node`.

`Organization`:

```
has_many :nodes
has_many :links, through: :nodes, source: :where_first_links
```

`Node`:

```
belongs_to :organization
has_many :where_first_links, class_name:  "Link",
                             foreign_key: "first_node_id"
has_many :where_second_links, class_name:  "Link",
                              foreign_key: "second_node_id"
```

`Link`:

```
belongs_to :first_node,  class_name: "Node"
belongs_to :second_node, class_name: "Node"
```

**Question:**: How can I associate `Link` back to `Organization`? I tried the line below but that does not seem to work (`ArgumentError: Unknown key: :through.`):

```
belongs_to :organization, 
           through: :first_node, 
           source: :where_first_links, 
           inverse_of: :links
```

Comment: `s/belongs_to/has_one/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

belongs_to association  not support through key

you should use has_one association

```
has_one :first_node_organization, 
        through: :first_node, 
        class_name: 'Organization', 
        source: :organization
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `has_one` instead of `belongs_to`.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_node,  class_name: "Node"
  belongs_to :second_node, class_name: "Node"

  has_one :organization, through: :first_node
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but `Link.first.organization` then responds with `ActiveRecord::InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the inverse association for organization (:links in Link)`.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that. I've corrected my answer (in case anyone comes a'looking). Incidentally you don't need to specify the `class_name` or `source` options if you just call the association on links `:organization`.